# Stuck and can´t print what i want in console Java

Tags: java, console

I want to print out the following in the console:

```
123456

12345

1234

123

12

1
```

But I can´t do it. Seems so simple but still I have this problem. I started with one for-loop nested into another but couldn´t get it working.

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

            for(int e=0;e<i;e++)

            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to show the code atleast

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: "I started with one for loope nestle into another" if by *nestle* you mean *nested* than that is right path. Show code including this approach.

Comment: "I started with one for loope nestle into another", i don´t see any nested loop in your edit.

Comment: Use a string, the function [String#substring(beginIndex:int, endIndex: int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and a loop. Happy coding.

Comment: public static void main(String aregs[]) {

  for (int i = 6; i >= 1; i--) {

   for (int e = 1; e <= i; e++)

   {
    System.out.print(e);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code completes your assignment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=7;i>0;i--){
        for(int e=1;e<i;e++)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
}
```

To get the behavior you want the outer for loop has to decrease the number with each subsequent iteration, while the inner loop has to start from 1 instead of 0.

I added another print so the lines match.